# Adding an initializer to a view controller results in an outlet being nil in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller as follows:

```
   class TutorialPageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate
    {
        @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
        var tutorialCategory    = TutorialCategory.enableShareContact

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
            self.pageViewController.delegate = self
            pageControl.numberOfPages  = 5

   ...
```

This runs without problem, however after adding an initializer the pageControl outlet is now nil in viewDidLoad resulting in an exception. This is the initializers added:

```
init(tutorialCategory: TutorialCategory)
{
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.tutorialCategory = tutorialCategory
}

convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    self.init(tutorialCategory: TutorialCategory.enableShareContact)
}
```

Why is adding the initializer having this effect of making the IBOutlet now become nil and how do I solve it?

(I tried adding a call to the VC's view within viewDidLoad to attempt to force load the outlet but it had no effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the outlet is setup by `super.init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, which you are no longer calling.

You probably want:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.tutorialCategory = .enableShareContact
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Don't override it as a convenience init.